# Observe LiveData property on local object changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have a ViewModel which encapsulates a user profile, which is backed by a Room Entity object. Currently I want to observe changes to the user's first name and last name in the ViewModel without having to update the user room entity via the full name property:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    ...

    private val repository = UserRepository(application)
    val user: LiveData<UserRoomEntity> = userRepository.getUser()

    // Note: have created extension methods for switchMap and toLiveData()
    val fullName: LiveData<String>
        get() = user.switchMap { it.calculateFullName().toLiveData() }

    ...
}
```

If I set either the `user.firstName` or `user.lastName` to a value, the `fullName` property won't be notified and update.  Only when I update `user` to the Room Database will it reflect the changes to `fullName`. I am wanting `fullName` to reflect any local change to `user.firstName` and `user.lastName` without updating the Room Database.

I've had success in achieving this by changing `fullName` to MutableLiveData and updating it on `firstName` and `lastName` changes, but I am not happy with the solution, as it requires `firstName` and `lastName` to be observed in the activity, which I want to avoid, and it seems hacky to me.

Is there a way to achieve this?